# Pre-pounding chicken

Tags: chicken, deep-frying, chicken-breast

I usually buy chicken about 1.2 kilograms at a time. I eat half of that in a day. I store the rest in the refrigerator. The usual recipe is breaded chicken and as such, requires pounding the chicken. When done once, pounding chicken isn't that hard or that of a hassle. When done regularly though, I feel that things can be done more efficiently. Is there a problem with pounding chicken at least a day or so before breading and cooking them (such as the chicken easily drying)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cover it well before refrigeration, it should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep the chicken wrapped up tight there should be no problem. I worked in a kitchen and pounded chicken in batches of 16 or 20, just use plastic wrap when you pound and wrap up the remainder like a burrito.